# flexslider not displaying / showing zero height on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having some problems trying to make my flexslider display on bootstrap modal. The flexslider only displays when I try to resize my browser or I tried to inspect element. The console doesn't show any errors

Here is my work in progress.

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://localhost/adspin/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://localhost/adspin/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image2.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://localhost/adspin/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://localhost/adspin/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image2.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#carousel').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      itemWidth: 210,
      itemMargin: 5,
      asNavFor: '#slider'
    });

    $('#slider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      smoothHeight: true,
      sync: "#carousel"
    });
});
```

## Updated Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
              animation: "slide",
              controlNav: false,
              animationLoop: false,
              slideshow: false,
              smoothHeight: true,
        });
});

$(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
         $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One think you need to do is just call/invoke your slider function on bootstrap modal shown like below

```
 $('#your-modal-id').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   // call your slider function
})
```

Comment: Yes its almost correct but. Just do one thing create your slider function outside the modal shown function and then call slider function into modal shown function. Hope its work

The code is not working because only your slider function render first and  your bootstrap modal still display none

Comment: check the updated code. Not sure if I got it right this time. Still learning javascript

Comment: No problem javascripts is awesome. And i have created a codepen for you kindly see. And please style accordingly 

http://codepen.io/harishgadiya/pen/rxrvmM

Comment: same outcome. I have to resize the browser in order for the slider to appear. I followed your example you have shown but no luck

Comment: I have update the codepen with image. Kindly check and its working fine on mine system and also i tested with different browser http://codepen.io/harishgadiya/pen/rxrvmM